# Running Traffic Light with Pi and Sending that info to another Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to program a raspberry pi 3 to run a traffic light on a breadboard.I also have a sensor that detects color of the traffic light, which is connected to the same raspberry pi. Can anyone help me with this? How would I do that, and also HOW can I send that detected information to another raspberry pi?

Thank you!

Comment: Simple way is to communicate your raspberries using HTTP (REST endpoints) or use MQTT protocol (Messaging protocol). WHat i have simply done for similar kind of project is , I manipulate GPIO using python and same python code has the HTTP REST endpoints written using Python Flask. I can write solution (Details) if you want that i have done.

Comment: If you could, that would be great!

Comment: Can you write python and http rest endpoints using any framework like python flask, bottle or any other????

Answer (score 1):

You can use messaging protocol like **RabbitMQ, MQTT** tech to make an easy communication between the raspberries.
But another Simplest way is to develop **HTTP REST endpoints** if you don't have stron background in messaging protocols (**MQTT**).
Easy way is develop HTTP REST endpoints using python flask.

1. Suppose you have a method in python flask as `turnOnLED()` bind with a URL as `/on` on Raspberry PI X. Now you can call this REST Endpoint using the IP of this raspberry **X** from another Raspberry **Y**.
2. You can similarly write a method in python to interact with `**GPIO**` and make that method available through your URL (ip/endpoints) to another Raspberry. From other Raspberry you can call that method by calling the URL for the first one.

Make research on **`RESTful APIs using Python`**, **`GPIO`**, **`PGPIOD`**, **`WiringPI`**, **`Pythong flask`** or any other framework to write REST Endpoints rapidly.
You need knowledge in all these buddy.